# "Score returned from FUN was not numeric,, Cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'"

Tags: r, algorithm, function, optimization, closures

I am following the instructions from this tutorial (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ParBayesianOptimization/vignettes/functionMaximization.html) on how to optimize functions using the R programming language.

I wanted to modify the example in this tutorial to include a slightly more complicated example.

I defined the following function :

```
#load necessary library
    library(ParBayesianOptimization)
    
       bayesian_function <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4) {
        var_1 <- sin(x1 + x2)
        var_2 <- cos(x1 - x2)
        var_3 <- x1 + x4
        var_4 <- x3 + x4 -7
        goal = sum(var_1 + var_2 + var_3 + var_4)
        
        return(goal)
        
    }
    
    
     FUN <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4) list(Score = bayesian_function)
```

I specified the ranges that the variables of the function can take:

```
 bounds <- list(x1 =c(20,40), x2 = c(30,45), x3 = c(10,20), x4 = c(10,50))
```

Then I ran the optimization algorithm :

```
   optObj <- bayesOpt(
        FUN = FUN
        , bounds = bounds
       , initPoints = 10
        , acq = "ei"
        , iters.n = 2
        , gsPoints = 25
    )
```

But this results in the following error:

```
Running initial scoring function 10 times in 1 thread(s)...  2.06 seconds
          x1       x2       x3       x4                             errorMessage
 1: 29.71786 30.04940 15.97740 44.48221 Score returned from FUN was not numeric.
 2: 32.82714 32.83628 10.38391 40.60989 Score returned from FUN was not numeric.

etc

Error in bayesOpt(FUN = FUN, bounds = bounds, initPoints = 10, acq = "ei",  : 
  Errors encountered in initialization are listed above.
```

Seeing as the error indicated that the "score returned from the function was not numeric", I decided to manually convert this into a "numeric type":

```
   bayesian_function <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4) {
    var_1 <- sin(x1 + x2)
    var_2 <- cos(x1 - x2)
    var_3 <- x1 + x4
    var_4 <- x3 + x4 -7
    goal = sum(var_1 + var_2 + var_3 + var_4)

    return(goal)

}


 FUN <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4) list(as.numeric(Score = bayesian_function))
```

Unfortunately, this is giving a new error:

```
Running initial scoring function 10 times in 1 thread(s)...  2.09 seconds
          x1       x2       x3       x4                                            errorMessage
 1: 37.78915 37.13628 16.12003 29.24897 cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'
 2: 32.58058 32.99083 11.03643 13.00817 cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'

etc

Error in bayesOpt(FUN = FUN, bounds = bounds, initPoints = 10, acq = "ei",  : 
  Errors encountered in initialization are listed above.
```

Can someone please show me how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: FUN <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4) list(Score = bayesian_function(x1, x2, x3, x4))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your indicated example this should work:

```
#load necessary library
library(ParBayesianOptimization)

bayesian_function <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4) {
    var_1 <- sin(x1 + x2)
    var_2 <- cos(x1 - x2)
    var_3 <- x1 + x4
    var_4 <- x3 + x4 -7
    goal = sum(var_1 + var_2 + var_3 + var_4)
    
    return(goal)
    
}
    
}
#test 
bayesian_function(1,2,3,4)
# [1] 5.681422

FUNwrapper <- function(x1,x2,x3,x4) list(
    "Score"=bayesian_function(x1=x1,
                              x2=x2,
                              x3=x3,
                              x4=x4)
)
FUNwrapper(1,2,3,4)
#$Score
#[1] 5.681422

bounds <- list(x1 =c(20,40), x2 = c(30,45), x3 = c(10,20), x4 = c(10,50))


optObj <- bayesOpt(
    FUN = FUNwrapper
    , bounds = bounds
    , initPoints = 10
    , acq = "ei"
    , iters.n = 2
    , gsPoints = 25
)
```

Output:

```
Running initial scoring function 10 times in 1 thread(s)...  0.83 seconds

Starting Epoch 1 
  1) Fitting Gaussian Process...
  2) Running local optimum search...        0.34 seconds
  3) Running FUN 1 times in 1 thread(s)...  0.09 seconds

Starting Epoch 2 
  1) Fitting Gaussian Process...
  2) Running local optimum search...        0.19 seconds
  3) Running FUN 1 times in 1 thread(s)...  0.09 seconds
>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! I tried running your code with "optObj <- bayesOpt(
    FUN = bayesian_function
    , bounds = bounds
    , initPoints = 1000
    , acq = "ei"
    , iters.n = 10
    , gsPoints = 25
)" ....and I got the following error " Error in rbindlist(scoreSummary) : 
  Column 2 of item 1 is length 6 inconsistent with column 1 which is length 100. Only length-1 columns are recycled. .... do you know why this error is produced? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can omit `FUN` and use `bayesian_function` directly as follows:

```
bayesian_function <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4) {
  var_1 <- sin(x1 + x2)
  var_2 <- cos(x1 - x2)
  var_3 <- x1 + x4
  var_4 <- x3 + x4 -7
  
  return(list(Score = var_1 + var_2 + var_3 + var_4))
}

bounds <- list(x1 =c(20,40), x2 = c(30,45), x3 = c(10,20), x4 = c(10,50))

optObj <- bayesOpt(
  FUN = bayesian_function
  , bounds = bounds
  , initPoints = 10
  , acq = "ei"
  , iters.n = 2
  , gsPoints = 25
)
```